# Node MySQL models

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Coming from codeigniter, I'm obviously used to having my controller call a model to get data from MySQL.

I have routes moved into their own controllers folder and I've googled a lot of tutorials but can never find anything that shows how to move queries out of the routes so they can potentially be reused.

Is this not a common practice or is my google-fu failing me?

And if I just don't know what to look for, any good tutorial links are more than welcome.

Comment: Queries? As in raw SQL strings? You can just put `export const myQuery = "select * from foo";` into a file and then `import {myQuery} from './some-file'` (assuming you're using import/export.... otherwise `exports.myQuery = ...` and `require(...)`

Comment: @mpen yeah that's basically what I'm referring too. Mostly trying to keep routes clean. Will doing import / export allow me to pass variables to the queries?

Comment: No, just export a function which returns a string then. Or use parameterized queries, which you should be using anyway. I recommend `node-mysql2` with named placeholders.

Comment: @mpen awesome info, I'll be checking that out for sure.  Thank you for the guidance